# BackgroundWorker, Delegate InvokeRequired?

Tags: vb.net, listview, delegates

I've been using a backgroundWorker and also a Delegate to add a listview item to the listview. My code downloads an image to an imagelist and then attempts to add the image to the listview. The first image is added but any other image in the imagelist cannot be added to the listview with out a cross-thread error. I can't understand why the first image works but none of the others. I realised by looking on this subject at this site that I would have to use InvokeRequired. Am I doing something wrong? Here's my code...

```
        Dim strPhotoLink As String = strPostContent.Substring(intPhotoLinkStartIndex + 35, ((intPhotoLinkEndIndex - intPhotoLinkStartIndex) - 29))
        lstPhotoLinks.Add(strPhotoLink)
        Try
            ImageListPhotos.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromStream(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strPhotoLink).GetResponse.GetResponseStream))

            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem("", ImageListPhotos.Images.Count - 1)
            Dim delAddListViewPhotoItem As DelegateAddListViewPhotoItem = New DelegateAddListViewPhotoItem(AddressOf AddListViewPhotoItem)
            delAddListViewPhotoItem.Invoke(lvi)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try

Private Delegate Sub DelegateAddListViewPhotoItem(item As ListViewItem)
Private Sub AddListViewPhotoItem(item As ListViewItem)
    If ListViewPhotos.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Dim del As New DelegateAddListViewPhotoItem(AddressOf AddListViewPhotoItem)
        ListViewPhotos.Invoke(del, item)
    Else
        ListViewPhotos.Items.Add(item)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is that first block of code located?  As posted it looks like you may be creating the LVI on one thread then trying to add it in another.  I cant see where images or imagelists are involved (or a BGW for that matter)

Comment: the first part of the code runs in the backgroundworker. It then calls the delegate to add the listview item. I'm I creating the listview item in the wrong place?

Comment: `the code runs in the backgroundworker` does that mean the `DoWork()` method?

Comment: Yes the 'do work' method.

Comment: The point of a BGW is to do some time consuming task on a thread other than the UI thread (the thread they were created on).  Controls can only be modified on the UI thread. so your code creates LVI on ThreadA (e.g.) then tries to add it to the LVI on the UI thread via the delegate

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I should do it? Thanks for your help Plutonix.

Comment: If it's at the end of your thread, you could use the [RunWorkerCompleted
 event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Well in the 'Do Work' method it's one big loop. Basically, parse a link, add it to an imagelist then add the image to the list view.

Comment: Where exactly, which line, is the error on.  I see 2 candidates:  the Imagelist is a component, not control, but I'm pretty sure the same rules apply (esp given the  mention of image failure).  Pass the new image recieved to the Delegate and let it add to the ImgList and create the LVI and add it to the LV

Comment: OK I'm gonna try that. I know there's a way to do it right. I had this project working two years ago. Thanks guys for all the input and explanations.